# Why this programe getting an error that is taking too much time to execute error

Tags: java

```
public static int meth(int N)
    {
         int count1=0;
            int count2=0;
            int tot=0;
           while(N>=1)
           {
                  if(N%2==0)
                  {
                      N=N/2;//2
                      count1++;//1
                      //i=0;
                  }
                  else if(N%2!=0)
                  {
                      N=(N+1)/2;
                      count2++;
                      //i=0;
                  }
                  else if(N==1)
                  {
                      count2++;
                      N=0;
                  }
              }
          tot=count1+count2;
          return tot;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
int i=meth(4);
System.out.println(i);
}
```

N/2 foods items if N is divisible by 2
(N+1)/2 food items if N is not divisible by 2.

Example 1:
Input:
N=4
Output:
3
Explanation:
In First second a person will eat (4/2) item after that
food item left will be 2. In 2nd second that person will eat
(2/2) item so food item left will be 1.In 2nd
second he will eat ((1+1)/2) item so food item
left will be 0.
Example 2:
Input:
N=0
Output:
0
Explanation:
There is no food items to eat.

Comment: because you have an infinite loop. your second if ```if(N%2!=0)``` will always execute when N = 1. and N will remain 1 because (1+1)/2 = 1

Comment: This code not passing  all test cases
N=7
And Your Code's output is:4
Its Correct output is:3

Comment: according to your logic the correct output for 7 would be 4. (1) 7 is odd so N = (7+1)/2=4 (2) 4 is even so N = 4/2 = 2 (3) 2 is even so N = 2/2 = 1 (4) N = 1 therefore end loop. total 4

Answer (score 0):

like I said in the comment, your code results in an infinite loop. The solution is simply switch your second and third if like so. this way N will get a chance to reach 0 and end the loop.

```
    public static int meth(int N){
        int count1=0;
        int count2=0;
        int tot=0;
        while(N>=1){
            if(N%2==0){
                N=N/2;//2
                count1++;//1
                //i=0;
            }else if(N==1){
                count2++;
                N=0;
            }else if(N%2!=0){
                N=(N+1)/2;
                count2++;
                //i=0;
            }
        }
        tot=count1+count2;
        return tot;
    }
```